# missing metadata on itunes aiff

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, metadata, aiff

I am writing the aiff metadata with this line:

```
ffmpeg -i uno.aiff -metadata title=Track -metadata artist=Band -f aiff dos.aiff
```

but iTunes done recognize the metadata. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-write_id3v2 1` as an output option:

```
ffmpeg -i in.aiff -c copy -write_id3v2 1 -metadata title="Title" \
-metadata artist="Artist" out.aiff
```

- You can add `-c copy` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encoding if you just want to add metadata.
- `-f aiff` is superfluous in your example since `ffmpeg` can guess the correct muxer via the output file name.
- See [AIFF muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#aiff-1).

Comment: I think your solution works, it was because my ffmpeg version was too old.

Comment: Also now I have a problem installing ffmpeg.

Comment: I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: @Jürgen You can [download a build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide). If you have any trouble you can ask at [su], #ffmpeg IRC, or ffmpeg-user mailing list.